# More efficient way to filter over a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, subset

The problem is this, I have a dataframe like so:

```
A B C D
2 3 X 5
7 2 5 7
1 2 7 9
3 4 X 9
1 2 3 5
6 3 X 8
```

I wish to iterate over the rows of the dataframe and every time column C=X I want to reset a counter and start adding the values in column B until column C=X again.  Then rince and repeat down the rows till complete.

Currently I am iterating over the rows using .iterrows(), comparing column C and then procedurally adding to a variable.

I'm hoping there is a more efficient 'pandas' like approach to doing something like this.

Comment: Can you give an example of your output? Also please share minimum code.

Comment: Please share the code you already have.

Comment: You are right, maybe you can rename each X variable to be unique (like x1, x2, ..., xn,) and then use a pandas groupby on the columns of the X's and use sum as aggregation operation?

Comment: X should be 3, 3 + 4, 3 + 4+ 3. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cumsum()` as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"B":[3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3],
                  "C":["X", 5, 7, "X", 3, "X"]})

df['C'].loc[df['C'] == "X"] = df['B'].loc[df['C'] == "X"].cumsum()
```

The output is

```
    B   C
0   3   3
1   2   5
2   2   7
3   4   7
4   2   3
5   3   10
```